# Div slide from the left side after a button is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

The picture explains it better than I do.

Before I click on it - [screenshot1](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0742bur0c0)

After: [screenshot2](http://awesomescreenshot.com/00d2bur92a)

It's a fixed button on the side of a window and it slides out when it's clicked.

I've been searching the web for so long and can't find the solution. Could you guys help me please?

Comment: you should put some code here. jsfiddle.net is your friend :)

Comment: may be the problem of space from right side when button clicked then one panel is open.so we guess that then panel doesn't have enough space from right side.so it slide left side with button..

Comment: I think you are asking like this : http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-jQuery-Plugin-For-Slide-Out-Tab-Feedback-Widget-Feedback-Me/

From here you can download fixed forms : There are lots of fixed forms are there : http://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/Contact%20Form/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below code can help you.

HTML

```
<section id="hiddenPanel" class="txt-highlight-color bg-color bg-pattern">
  <span id="close-bar" class="myButton"> < </span>
</section>
```

CSS

```
#hiddenPanel {position:fixed; top:0; right:-200px; width:200px; background-color:grey; height:250px;}
#close-bar { position:absolute; left:-20px; background:red; color:white; width:20px; height:250px;}
```

jQuery Code

```
var speed = 300;
    $('#close-bar').on('click', function(){

        var $$ = $(this),
            panelWidth = $('#hiddenPanel').outerWidth();

        if( $$.is('.myButton') ){
            $('#hiddenPanel').animate({right:0}, speed);
            $$.removeClass('myButton')
        } else {
            $('#hiddenPanel').animate({right:-panelWidth}, speed);
            $$.addClass('myButton')
        }

    });
```

[http://jsfiddle.net/Rxsd5/](http://jsfiddle.net/Rxsd5/1/)

Answer (score 0):

basically i do in jquery, however i given a code for css.. i used hover instead of click. And changes these css values and play with it..

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="slide">
     //content or form goes here.. 
    </div>
</div>

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px; 
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#slide {
    position: absolute;
    left: -100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    transition: 1s;
}
.wrapper:hover #slide {
    transition: 1s;
    left: 0;
}
```